# Why is docker still running CMD when overridden in by docker run?

Tags: docker, docker-entrypoint

I have a Dockerfile with the following `CMD` as the last line

```
CMD ["/usr/local/myapp/bin/startup.sh", "docker"]
```

Part of a script that is executed against the docker image during startup is as follows

```
# find directory of cacerts file in DOCKER_JAVA_HOME of container
DOCKER_CACERTS_DIR=$(dirname "$(docker run "$DOCKER_IMAGE_ID" find "$DOCKER_JAVA_HOME" -name cacerts)")
```

However, this still executes the `CMD` line from my Dockerfile.

I have found that I can alter this behaviour by changing the line in the script as follows.

```
# find directory of cacerts file in DOCKER_JAVA_HOME of container
DOCKER_CACERTS_DIR=$(dirname "$(docker run --entrypoint find "$DOCKER_IMAGE_ID"  "$DOCKER_JAVA_HOME" -name cacerts)")
```

However, I didn't think this would be necessary.  Is it normal for docker to execute the `CMD` when overridden in the `docker run` command?  I thought this was supposed to be one of the differences between using `CMD` and `ENTRYPOINT`, that you could easily override `CMD` without using the `--entrypoint` flag.

In case it's important, this is using docker version `17.03.0-ce`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image being run has an `ENTRYPOINT` defined somewhere. Probably in the image you are building `FROM` if there isn't one in your `Dockerfile`.

When `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` are defined, Docker will pass the `CMD` to the `ENTRYPOINT` as arguments. From there, it's up to the `ENTRYPOINT` executable to decide what to do.

The arguments could be ignored completely, modified as the entry point sees fit or it can pass the complete command on to be run. That behaviour is image specific.

Comment: `ENTRYPOINT` was defined on the image I was building `FROM`